# Ellipsize text on basis of characters not words

Tags: android

Searched a lot on this question but still without a perfect answer. I want to ellipsize my text on basis of characters. Right now when I ellipsize the Text it does it on basis of words.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_drop_down_arrow_transparent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:text="North West Delhi"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size18sp" />
```

When i give text as "NORTH WEST DELHI". It gives me output as **"NORTH WEST...    "** and leaves a lot of space at the end. I want the output as **"NORTH WEST DEL..."**
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to use your own logic for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below attrubute to your textview you will get expected result:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But singleLine is depricated. Will it effect the code ?

Comment: There is an issue in code so you can use this code. When ellipse issue fixed with maxLines then you can change back to your code.

Comment: @Matrix if answer works then accept it, it may help to someone.